Inverse Problem: Using LightGBM model to recommend X (feature) ranges to achieve a specific y (target) range
I am trying to build a LightGBM regression model, where in I have aroud 15-20 Input features and my target variable within a range of 20-40.
I have used the SHAP beeswarm plot to kind of understand the importance of each feature (feature names hidden due to sensitivity of data)

Now, the user wants to me to create an optimization model based on this LightGBM model, where in an expected range of Y-Variable will be entered and the model will return the ideal range of each input variable (X, 15-20 features) to achieve the same. The problem is more like a Y-variable will be entered and in return the range of each X variable would be returned.
The challenge over here is however, the combination 15-20 features are required to achieve the Y-variable expected range, so the model recommendation also needs to take care of the same.
Is there any scikit-learn library which can be used to solve this problem? Or how can I achieve the solution in this case?
I have went through many similar questions but none of them are exactly what I am looking for.

Given a target range for Y. Why don't you just sample the input space densely and check whether the input is mapped into the target range? This will give you the inverse image of the target range to any desired precision.

This looks like a response-surface problem, look at this stored search. You might also add the tag [tag:experiment-design]
